# What are the actual limits of a bitmap in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, bitmap

As I can read it from [this article](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1426) the maximum square bitmap Flash can handle is 4,095 x 4,095 (which results in 16,769,025 pixels and bla-bla-bla). So, they say if I try to go to 4,096 x 4,096, I'll fail. But I have tried to load and display a bitmap image sized 4,096 x 4,096, and it worked well. Then, I even tried an image sized 5000 x 5000, and that was alright too. What do I not understand? What are the actual limits and how to calculate them?

Answer (score 3):

look at this http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/496/cpsid_49662.html

the actual size limit is 16,777,215 pixels (the decimal equivalent of 0xFFFFFF)

Answer (score 0):

I think these limits refer to what you can create in flash via the bitmap class, not what you can load externally...but I could be wrong.

Comment: yes, you can load whatever from the net via a Loader\URLLoader\Socket, but you can't put the data you load into a BitmapData if the size exceeds the limits BitmapData objects have.
so, if you try to load a 5000000x400000500450004 wide bitmap, you can, but you can't do nothing with that (unless you split it)

Comment: @pigiuz, how do you split an image of that size?

Comment: @zzzzBov it must be in a raw format (or compressed with zlib).As you load it (via urlloader or socket) you split the resulting bytearray in chunks and you can populate some pregenerated bitmapdatas with them.Example:you're loading a 5120x5120 raw 24bits img. you load it via urlloader and get its bytearray. then, you create n bitmapdata tiles (10x10 512px side) and n bytearrays(512x512*4).then you cycle the whole stride and put the read data in the bytearray associated to the proper tile. lastly you cycle all tiles and call setPixels for each of them passing the associated buffer as an argument

Comment: @pigiuz, I'm going to write a question so that you can post that as an answer.

Comment: @pigiuz, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583250/how-does-one-load-and-split-a-massive-image-in-flash).