# How does one load and split a massive image in flash?

Tags: flash, image-loading

How do you load an image that exceeds the `4096×4096` limitations of flash while splitting it?

**Note**: This is a direct extension of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216081/what-are-the-actual-limits-of-a-bitmap-in-flash/4216577#4216577).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it must be in a raw format (or compressed with zlib).As you load it (via urlloader or socket) you split the resulting bytearray in chunks and you can populate some pregenerated bitmapdatas with them.Example:you're loading a 5120x5120 raw 24bits img. you load it via urlloader and get its bytearray. then, you create n bitmapdata tiles (10x10 512px side) and n bytearrays(512x512*4).then you cycle the whole stride and put the read data in the bytearray associated to the proper tile. lastly you cycle all tiles and call setPixels for each of them passing the associated buffer as an argumen

Answer (score 1):

I've given an answer to such a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486103/bitmap-too-big-as3/5486279). When loaded to a ByteArray as a bitmap you can split it as you want... Or you can even find/write a C program which does it for you.